# C# XML Parsing using XmlReader in MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I tried to code, so data from XML data should be displayed in View. However I have trouble with compilation of the code. It says Value cannot be empty in place of lst.Add(...). How to solve this? Maybe add multidimensional array? How? XML data feed link is in the code.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Meeting> lst = new List<Meeting>();
        XmlReader read = XmlReader.Create(@"https://tatts.com/pagedata/racing/2011/10/5/RaceDay.xml");
        while (read.Read())
        {
            if (read.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && read.LocalName == "Meeting")
            {
                lst.Add(new Meeting
                {
                        VennueName = (read.GetAttribute("VenueName")),
                        RaceNo = int.Parse(read.GetAttribute("RaceNo")),
                        CloseTime = read.GetAttribute("CloseTime")
                });
            }
        }
        return View(lst);
    }
```

This is the Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication12.Models.Meeting>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <li>@item.VennueName;</li>
    <ul>
        <li>@item.RaceNo - @item.CloseTime</li>
    </ul>
}
</ul>
```

Also I have model named Meeting:

```
public class Meeting
    {
        public string VennueName { get; set; }
        public int RaceNo { get; set; }
        public string CloseTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried XLinq instead? Makes this kind of thing dramatically simpler.

Comment: @CoryNelson But XmlReader I guess would be the best, because I will be using huge xml data feed further. So I decided not to use XLinq. Is it good?

Comment: Yep, that's a good reason to use XmlReader.

Comment: I'd also recommend using LINQ to XML. Your linked XML file is about 350Kb - that's not particularly huge.  Your code doesn't match the file, however - `Meeting` does not have a `RaceNo` or a `CloseTime` attribute.

Comment: @CharlesMager So do you recommend to create other model classes for other attributes? And what is the maximum recommended XML file weigth to use LINQ to XML?

Comment: Can you recommend any book, which discusses mainly about xml parsing. So I could understand about xml parsing perfectly?

Comment: It depends what data you need out of the XML.  What you have now doesn't make sense - two of the properties are on `Race`, of which a `Meeting` contains multiple.  It's not clear what values you'd expect there.